# Diagonally Split Button with 2 colors WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, button, colors

I would like to know if its possible to create a button in WPF, that is split in half diagonally. In addition, would it also be possible to individually color them?
The button parts don't need to be clickable, as long as I can color them that way, I can figure out a way around that.

I have tried with gradients but I can't turn off interpolation, so thats out of the question.

[An Image of what I am thinking of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUEIg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

certainly can be done with gradient brush:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" BorderThickness="2"
        Background="Blue" Foreground="Red" BorderBrush="Black"> 
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=Foreground.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Offset="0.49"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=BorderBrush.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Offset="0.495"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=BorderBrush.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Offset="0.505"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Offset="0.505"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

[image: gradient]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.